# Can't get the height of my nav/div to offset during scroll animation to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am unable to get the height of my navigation.

**Attempt #1:**

```
$("#process-link").click(function() {
    $('html, body, #project-container').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#process-work").offset().top
    }, 2000 + $("nav#primary").height());
});
```

**Attempt #2:**

```
var headerHeight = $("nav#primary").height();

    $.address.change(function(evt) {
    var target = "#" + evt["pathNames"][0]; //Get the target from the event data

    // If there's been some content requested go to it…else go to the top
    if(evt["pathNames"][0]) {
        var scrollToPosition = $(target).offset().top - headerHeight;
        $('html, body, #project-container').animate({ 'scrollTop': scrollToPosition }, 600);
    } else {
        $('html, body, #project-container').animate({ 'scrollTop': '0' }, 600);
    }

    return false;
});
```

**Attempt #3**

```
$(function() {

        $('#process-link').click(function() {
            $("html, body, #project-container").animate({
                scrollTop: $( "#process-work" ).offset().top + $('nav#primary').height() 
            }, 2000);

            return false;
        });
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<nav id="primary">Content</nav>    
<div id="arrow-nav" class="container-full clearfix">Content</div>

<div id="project">
        <div id="project-container">
            <div class="container">
                <section>
                    <p class="sm-title">Client:</p>
                    <h2 id="project-title"></h2>
                    <p id="project-description"></p>
                    <a id="process-link">View Process <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="process-work">
                            <div class="col-6 fixme">
                                <h2 id="process-title">Process Work</h2>
                                <p id="process-description"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <div id="process-wireframes" class="owl-theme owl-carousel"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- end process-work-->
                    </div>

                </section>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end project container -->
    </div><!--closes project-->
```

I'm trying to make it so once #process-link is clicked it slides you to #process-work and calculates the height of nav#primary and #arrow-nav and offsets accordingly.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML, please ?

Comment: What does "completely broke the site" mean? Please post actual error messages.

Comment: In your first attempt, you are adding the nav height to the animation duration (2000 + height) instead of the scrollTop value. Is that a mistake in your question or your actual code? If the latter, then that could be your problem. Otherwise, please add the HTML and describe which element should scroll to where.

Comment: @C14L "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'change' of undefined"

Comment: @Lesley definitely a mistake in the code. I need to add it to the scrollTop value. I've updated the post with HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This javascript currently achieved what I wanted to do. I grouped all div elements into one called #project-content and calculated the height of that plus the nav. Because the page is fixed it was causing issues.

**HTML**

```
<div id="project-content">
   <p class="sm-title">Client:</p>
   <h2 id="project-title"></h2>
   <p id="project-description"></p>
   <div style="background:#919191" class="hr"></div>
   <a id="project-link" target="_blank">View Website <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
   <a id="process-link" data-type="slideTo" data-target="process-work">View Process <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
   <div id="project-tag"></div>
   <div id="project-images"></div>
</div><!--end project content-->
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#process-link').click(function() {
        $("html, body, #project-container").animate({
            scrollTop: $('nav#primary').height() + $("#arrow-nav").height() + $("#project-content").height() + 30
        }, 2000);

        return false;
    });
```

Look at the OP to see the divs that also exist in the document and what I am calculating. `#project-container` has `padding-top:60px;` which I think also affected the offset, which is why I added `30`.

Comment: Anyone think this is the wrong way to approach this? I don't want to accept this until I know this is a good enough answer.

Comment: Rather than hardcoding the 30px, I would find what element is setting it and dynamically grab the size. That way if your stylesheet changes you don't have to worry about editing this js. For example if the 30px is really coming from half your `#project-container`'s `padding-top` you would write: `$('#project-container').css('padding-top') / 2`